# Making AJAX load call to last row in a table

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table which looks like ,

```
<table id="MyTable">
 <thead>/*Some th elements*/</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to append a tr to the last row using the AJAX Load() method.

Here's my code,

```
$('#MyTable tbody tr:last').parent().load("/Index/LoadMoreData", dataObject);
```

which is creating nested tr , this type of a structure

```
<table id="MyTable">
 <thead>/*Some th elements*/</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <tr></tr> // want this tr like other trs
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

which is not what I expect. Please let me know the appropriate selector to load the tr to proper structure.
TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The load method only replaces the content of the element you've selected, it doesn't append to the parent. You'll need to use the get method and write your own function to append the row.

```
$.get('/Index/LoadMoreData', dataObject, function(data){ 
  $('#MyTable tbody').append(data);
});
```

Comment: Be aware, if data passed to the load() method is an object, POST method is assumed. The more relevant method would be then to use `$.post`, if that matters...

Comment: I'm not sure that's accurate, when using $.get the dataObject is converted into url arguments, and not the body of a post request.

Answer (score 2):

try this:-

```
$('#MyTable tbody tr:last').after($('<tr/>').load("/Index/LoadMoreData", dataObject));
```

if data is already pre-wrapped tr tag then you can use this:-

```
$('#MyTable tbody tr:last').after($('<tr/>').load("/Index/LoadMoreData", dataObject).contents().unwrap());
```

Comment: That's assuming that the data loaded is not already pre-wrapped in `<tr>` tags — if it is (which from the OP's question I deduced to be the likely situation), you might want to unwrap it first :)